# PHP project working correctly in local host but not in remote server

Tags: javascript, ajax

i cant trace out the problem am new to remote server with php

here is the part of my program where problem occurs

```
function handleLogin(email, password, callback){
    var jsonToReturn = "";

    $.ajax(appRoot+'access/login', {
        method: "POST",
        data: {email:email, password:password}
    }).done(function(returnedData){
        if(returnedData.status === 1){
            jsonToReturn = {status:1, msg:"Authenticated..."};
        }

        else{
            //display error messages
            jsonToReturn = {status:0, msg:"Invalid email/password combination"};
        }

        typeof(callback) === "function" ? callback(jsonToReturn) : "";

    }).fail(function(){
        //set error message based on the internet connectivity of the user
        var msg = "Log in failed. Please check your internet connection and try again later.";

        //display error messages
        jsonToReturn = {status:0, msg:msg};

        typeof(callback) === "function" ? callback(jsonToReturn) : "";
    });
}
```

In local server it works fine but in remote server it call fails function and displays message "Log in failed. Please check your internet connection and try again later.";

thanks in advance

Comment: Open your browser's devtools and check the Network tab, one of the requests will be red and depending on your server configuration you might be able to read the error.

Comment: Your `appRoot` variable/constant might be wrong, I mean there could be a lot of things wrong here but it's probably a server issue if the route is right.

Comment: var appRoot = setAppRoot("brizotrade", "brizotrade");

Comment: i have deployed this code in brizotrade.mydomain.com.... means i have deployed in my sub domain

Comment: Maybe CORS problem, you must be facing. Check your `console` tab in developers tool